Why can't pnpm resolve my workspace package and run it?
I've got a typescript cli project in a workspace managed with turbo and pnpm. It works beautifully. I import it into another project in the workspace, as a dev dependency.
  "devDependencies": {
    "@simplyfirst/my-cli": "workspace:^",
    ...

When I try to run it only using the package name, pnpm cannot find it...
PS C:\dev\simplyfirst-catalogues\catalogues\acme-pvc> pnpm exec @simplyfirst/my-cli    
The system cannot find the path specified.
 ERR_PNPM_RECURSIVE_EXEC_FIRST_FAIL  Command "@simplyfirst/my-cli" not found

This is very odd, because the imported dependency's package.json correctly points to the bundle...
{
  "name": "@simplyfirst/my-cli",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",

...and if I call the bundle directly, it all works no problem...
PS C:\dev\simplyfirst-catalogues\catalogues\acme-pvc> node node_modules/@simplyfirst/my-cli/dist/bundle.js
  _____              _             _                          _             _             _____              _ 
 | ____|_  _____ ___| |   ___  ___| |_   _ __ ___   ___  _ __| |_    __   _(_)_   _____  | ____|_  _____ ___| |
 |  _| \ \/ / __/ _ \ |  / _ \/ __| __| | '_ ` _ \ / _ \| '__| __|   \ \ / / \ \ / / _ \ |  _| \ \/ / __/ _ \ |
 | |___ >  < (_|  __/ | |  __/\__ \ |_  | | | | | | (_) | |  | |_ _   \ V /| |\ V /  __/ | |___ >  < (_|  __/ |
 |_____/_/\_\___\___|_|  \___||___/\__| |_| |_| |_|\___/|_|   \__( )   \_/ |_| \_/ \___| |_____/_/\_\___\___|_|
                                                                 |/

I've tried calling it with npx, with pnpm without exec and a number of other permutations. Why won't pnpm run my package?

Not sure if that will solve your issue. But under similar circumstancies I was unable to intall local package with pnpm. It did not recognize it and was giving me "not on npm registry"
My take is set the option:
pnpm config set link-workspace-packages true

It will look for local packages first. Refer to this link.

pnpm will always link the workspace package if the workspace: range protocol is used, so this setting will have no effect in OP’s situation.
